# App Engine (Python) Datastore Precall API Hooks

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

**Background**

So let's say I'm making app for GAE, and I want to use [API Hooks](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/hooks.html).

*BIG EDIT*: In the original version of this question, I described my use case, but some folks correctly pointed out that it was not really suited for API Hooks.  Granted!  Consider me helped.  But now my issue is academic: I still don't know how to use hooks in practice, and I'd like to.  I've rewritten my question to make it much more generic.

---

**Code**

So I make a model like this:

```
class Model(db.Model):
    user = db.UserProperty(required=True)
    def pre_put(self):
        # Sets a value, raises an exception, whatever.  Use your imagination
```

And then I create a db_hooks.py:

```
from google.appengine.api import apiproxy_stub_map

def patch_appengine(): 
    def hook(service, call, request, response):
        assert service == 'datastore_v3'
        if call == 'Put':
            for entity in request.entity_list():
                entity.pre_put()

    apiproxy_stub_map.apiproxy.GetPreCallHooks().Append('preput',
                                                        hook,
                                                        'datastore_v3')
```

Being TDD-addled, I'm making all this using [GAEUnit](http://code.google.com/p/gaeunit/), so in gaeunit.py, just above the main method, I add:

```
import db_hooks
db_hooks.patch_appengine()
```

And then I write a test that instantiates and puts a Model.

---

**Question**

While `patch_appengine()` is definitely being called, the hook never is.  What am I missing?  How do I make the pre_put function actually get called?

Answer (score 2):

Hooks are a little low level for the task at hand. What you probably want is a custom property class. DerivedProperty, from [aetycoon](http://github.com/arachnid/aetycoon), is just the ticket.

Bear in mind, however, that the 'nickname' field of the user object is probably not what you want - per [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userclass.html#User_nickname), it's simply the user part of the email field if they're using a gmail account, otherwise it's their full email address. You probably want to let users set their own nicknames, instead.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that within the context of the `hook()` function an `entity` is not an instance of db.Model as you are expecting.

In this context `entity` is the protocol buffer class confusingly referred to as entity ([entity_pb](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/datastore/entity_pb.py)). Think of it like a JSON representation of your real entity, all the data is there, and you could build a *new* instance from it, but there is no reference to your memory-resident instance that is waiting for it's callback.

Monkey patching all of the various `put/delete` methods is the best way to setup Model-level callbacks as far as I know†

Since there doesn't seem to be that many resources on how to do this safely with the newer async calls, here's a BaseModel that implements before_put, after_put, before_delete & after_delete hooks:

```
class HookedModel(db.Model):

    def before_put(self):
        logging.error("before put")

    def after_put(self):
        logging.error("after put")

    def before_delete(self):
        logging.error("before delete")

    def after_delete(self):
        logging.error("after delete")

    def put(self):
        return self.put_async().get_result()

    def delete(self):
        return self.delete_async().get_result()

    def put_async(self):
        return db.put_async(self)

    def delete_async(self):
        return db.delete_async(self)
```

Inherit your model-classes from HookedModel and override the before_xxx,after_xxx methods as required.

Place the following code somewhere that will get loaded globally in your applicaiton (like `main.py` if you use a pretty standard looking layout). This is the part that calls our hooks:

```
def normalize_entities(entities):
    if not isinstance(entities, (list, tuple)):
        entities = (entities,)
    return [e for e in entities if hasattr(e, 'before_put')]

# monkeypatch put_async to call entity.before_put
db_put_async = db.put_async
def db_put_async_hooked(entities, **kwargs):
    ents = normalize_entities(entities)
    for entity in ents:
        entity.before_put()
    a = db_put_async(entities, **kwargs)
    get_result = a.get_result
    def get_result_with_callback():
        for entity in ents:
            entity.after_put()
        return get_result()
    a.get_result = get_result_with_callback
    return a
db.put_async = db_put_async_hooked


# monkeypatch delete_async to call entity.before_delete
db_delete_async = db.delete_async
def db_delete_async_hooked(entities, **kwargs):
    ents = normalize_entities(entities)
    for entity in ents:
        entity.before_delete()
    a = db_delete_async(entities, **kwargs)
    get_result = a.get_result
    def get_result_with_callback():
        for entity in ents:
            entity.after_delete()
        return get_result()
    a.get_result = get_result_with_callback
    return a
db.delete_async = db_delete_async_hooked
```

You can save or destroy your instances via model.put() or any of the db.put(), db.put_async() etc, methods and get the desired effect.

*†would love to know if there is an even better solution!?*

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that Hooks are really going to solve this problem. The Hooks will only run in the context of your AppEngine application, but the user can change their nickname outside of your application using Google Account settings. If they do that, it won't trigger any logic implement in your hooks.

I think that the real solution to your problem is for your application to manage its own nickname that is independent of the one exposed by the Users entity.

Comment: Ah, darn, you're absolutely right.  So what about enforcing uniqueness per account?  Wouldn't that be done best by checking before a put?

Comment: If you want to enforce uniqueness, then you would have to check before the first put that creates the entity in the datastore. If you forbid the user from changing that value -- which is a good idea -- you only need to check on creation.

Comment: True, and in both cases, I'm just going to write a method that does the checks and updates I want before putting, then use that instead of put().  Thank you.