# Override save, put, get, etc... methods in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, overriding

Is it possible to override methids for db.Model in Google App Engine?
I want to declare beforeSave, afterSave methods, etc.. to create automatic tagging system.

I know there are hooks, but it seems to me a wrong way to solve this issue :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to override these methods. Have a look at this [blog post by Nick Johnson](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/Pre--and-post--put-hooks-for-Datastore-models).The hooked model class looks this:

```
class HookedModel(db.Model):
  def before_put(self):
    pass

  def after_put(self):
    pass

  def put(self, **kwargs):
    self.before_put()
    super(HookedModel, self).put(**kwargs)
    self.after_put()
```

Read the blog to see how to handle the `db.put()` method too.

You might also be interested on ["derived properties"](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/9/Custom-Datastore-Properties-1-DerivedProperty).

Comment: I really do have to get in faster. ;)

Comment: put() should return a Key - I've submitted an edit to this answer to add that in.

Comment: @wodow, it is *not* acceptable for you to edit someone else's code to add your own code, *especially if it is the accepted answer*. If you really feel that you have something to add, then either add your own answer, or ask the answer author to adjust their code. I have rolled back your edit.

Comment: @Sheridan, ok, sorry! (not a wiki)

Answer (score 1):

I posted an extension to jbochi's HookedModel class so that the `before_put` and `after_put` methods are correctly invoked when called from `db.put()` and the `_async` family of functions.

See [AppEngine PreCall API hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351752/app-engine-python-datastore-precall-api-hooks)

Answer (score 1):

I've attempted to improve upon the answer by @jbochi:

1. According to https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_put , `put()` should return a `Key`, so the return value from the library should be passed through.
2. `db.Model.save()`, while deprecated, is (a) sometimes still used, (b) meant to be a synonym for `put()` and (c) apparently not called directly by `put()` - so should be handled manually.

Revised code:

```
class HookedModel(db.Model):
  def before_put(self):
    pass

  def after_put(self):
    pass

  def put(self, **kwargs):
    self.before_put()
    result = super(HookedModel, self).put(**kwargs)
    self.after_put()
    return result

  def save(self, **kwargs):
    self.before_put()
    result = super(HookedModel, self).save(**kwargs)
    self.after_put()
    return result
```

You should still read http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/Pre--and-post--put-hooks-for-Datastore-models if you wish to use the monkeypatching, or Chris Farmiloe's answer for use of the async methods.