# AppEngine Bulkloader generate data during import

Tags: google-app-engine, bulkloader

I imported a CSV into the datastore and want to generate a field StringListProperty with a custom action during import (e.g. index generation, doing some calculations). I tried to override the put() method of my model like it is described in question [Override save, put, get, etc... methods in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752601/override-save-put-get-etc-methods-in-google-app-engine), but during bulkloader import this has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

look into `google.appengine.ext.bulkload.bulkloader_wizard`, there isn't a default transformer for list of str/unicode. You have to make your own.