# Trigger event on app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, events

I'm looking for a way to trigger an event on app engine when a User is created. I have something like

```
def create_user(data):
    user = new User(data)
    user.put()
    trigger('user_created', user)
    return user
```

This way, external modules may be able to modify the entity when a new user is created. I imagine I could add something like

```
add_hook('user_created', some_function)
```

to external modules (on app initialization). This function would add fields to the entity like

```
def some_function(user):
    user.data = 'some value'
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this on app engine ?

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752601/override-save-put-get-etc-methods-in-google-app-engine) and [blog post](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/Pre--and-post--put-hooks-for-Datastore-models) might be useful

Answer (score 1):

Generally this is something you would handle with [the task queue](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/). When you create a new user, fire off a batch of tasks to do whatever follow-up work is appropriate. You can define the list of tasks elsewhere, and override the `put()` method of your User model to enqueue them.

This is kind of a hook enforced within your model. If you need a hook enforced at the datastore, you can try the new [Prospective Search API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/prospectivesearch/). I haven't tried it, but according to [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/prospectivesearch/functions.html), you can specify a model, a query, and a task handler URL that will be called when new entities matching the query are created.

Comment: The User entity is json-serialized and returned to the client after additional fields are added to it (by the external modules), so this couldn't be done with a task queue on the background. Maybe Prospective search could help, but I'd need to match any User entity added to the datastore. Can it be simpler ?