# GAE datastore: filter by date interval

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have this model:

```
class Vehicle(db.Model):
    ...
    start_production_date = db.DateProperty()
    end_production_date = db.DateProperty()
```

I need to filter, for example, all vehicles in production within, say, 2010:

I thought I could do:

```
q = (Vehicle.all()
    .filter('start_production_date >=', datetime(2010, 1, 1))
    .filter('end_production_date <', datetime(2011, 1, 1)))
```

buy I get `BadFilterError`:

```
BadFilterError: invalid filter: Only one property per query may have inequality filters (<=, >=, <, >)..
```

so, how do I acheive this? Moreover this seems to me a quite common task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went with this solution:

I set in model a `ListProperty` item containing all years the model was crafted:

```
vhl.production_years = range(start_production_date.year, end_production_date + 1)
```

Then test:

```
q = (Vehicle.all()
    .filter('production_years =', 2010))
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to change your model to something like this:

```
class Vehicle(db.Model):
    ...
    start_production_date = db.DateProperty()
    start_production_year = db.IntegerProperty()
    start_production_month = db.IntegerProperty()
    start_production_day = db.IntegerProperty()

    end_production_date = db.DateProperty()
    end_production_year = db.IntegerProperty()
    end_production_month = db.IntegerProperty()
    end_production_day = db.IntegerProperty()
```

Update these new values on every put (you could [override put](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2753747/8418)) and the simply:

```
# specific year

q = (Vehicle.all()
    .filter('start_production_year =', 2010))

# specific year, different months

q = (Vehicle.all()
    .filter('start_production_year =', 2010)
    .filter('start_production_month IN', [1, 2, 3, 4]))

# different years

q = (Vehicle.all()
    .filter('start_production_year IN', [2010, 2011, 2012]))
```

Comment: Sorry but this does not solves the problem: how do I filter models in production in 2010? that year is **between** start and end date. There are models, for example, which started being built in 2000 and gone out of production in 2012 and so on.

Comment: @neurino you can create these lists manually and then use the `IN` operator. For example if `start_list = [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004]` and `end_list = [2009, 20010, 20011, 20012, 2013]` you can use the two filters: `.filter('start_production_year IN', start_list).filter('end_production_year IN', end_list)`

Comment: @neurino I'm not sure if you can find anything better.. since you are not allowed to use two inequality operators in the same filter..

Comment: I get your point what I cannot understand is how App Engine can be a powerful tool if tied to such limitations of its Datastore. The vast majority of hosted apps **does not rely on billions of records like Facebook**, a query with two inequalities on 10k records is a task that won't put the db under stress... give me back MySQL then, maybe as a paid service...

Comment: @neurino They have their reasons.. but you have to read all these limitations before deciding what you want to do or assuming that it will just work because it's powerful, or just because we want that. Also datastore is not designed for 10k records but for millions.. so it might be a bit more complicated than you think :)

Comment: no intention to be polemic with you **but** does app engine is oriented to whom? Reading how it's presented I'd guess _any developer_ not _big corporates_...

Comment: @neurino https://www.khanacademy.org/ is one huge example :) http://bjk5.com/post/30813320623/what-traffic-from-60-minutes-looks-like